# replace values of a data frame regarding another matrix values

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, matrix, replace

I have a large matrix that a subset of that would be like below:

```
mat<-read.table(text = "links   X1  X2  X3  X4
a,b 1.2222  1.5147654   1.5147654   1.5147654
a,c 5.444   1.9763846   1.9763846   1.9763846
c,m 8.99999 1.5515179   -2.3816097  1.5515179
d,e 5.44643 2.2518252   2.2518252   -1.3523473
f,g 7.65656 1.8534944   1.8534944   1.8534944
f,k 2.5645  1.7646614   1.7646614   1.7646614
")
```

and a data frame as follows:

```
df<-read.table(text="links  values
a,b 2.716741
                    a,c 0
                    f,g 0
                    f,k 1.4534

                ",header=T,stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I want to replace the values of my df according to my matrix information such that:

if the values in the first column of my data frame exist in the first column of my matrix, the in the front value of that should be replaced with one of the values in the existed line of the matrix. The replacing value in the matrix can be distinguished with the below code:

```
x<-floor((df_dist_mat[i,2]-0.75)/0.5)+1
```

x value refers to X1 or ... or X4 column. The final result should be like this:

```
links   values
a,b 1.5147654
a,c 0
f,g 0
f,k 1.7646614
```

I write the below code but I don't know how to get the final result:

```
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {

      if (df[i,2]>0&& df[i,2]<=15) {

        x<-floor((df[i,2]-0.75)/0.5)+1

    }

  }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That worked for me:

1) you need to add `header = TRUE` in your `mat` - dataframe

2) based on your comments I adjusted the loop:

```
library(tidyverse) # you need dplyr and tidyr

df <- df %>% # prepare the df to splite the link column
  separate(links, c("links1", "links2"))

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (df[i,3]>0 && df[i,3]<=15) {
    var1 <- df[i, 1] # get character of link1
    var2 <- df[i, 2] # get character of link2
    x <- floor(((df[i,3]-0.75)/0.5)+1) # check the value and define the X column

    # subset the mat dataset based on link names
    # example "a,b" == "b,a" OR "a,b" == "a,b" OR "b,a" == "b,a"
    foo <- mat %>%  
             select(links, paste0("X", x)) %>% 
             filter(links == paste0(var1, ",", var2) | links == paste0(var2, ",", var1))

    df[i,3] <- foo[1,2]
  }
}

# get back the old form of your df
df <- df %>% 
  unite(links, links1, links2, sep = ",")
```

output will be:

```
  links   values
1   a,b 1.514765
2   a,c 0.000000
3   f,g 0.000000
4   f,k 1.764661
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. However, when I check it on my real data with this structure, I faced NA values in the result. I think the problem is in the last line of the code foo[1,2]. What do you think?

Comment: have you checked, that the `mat` dataframe has header names with X2, X3,... instead of V2, V3,... ?

Comment: Yes, I have checked them.

Comment: I think we have to consider both characters for example in the first line a,b and b,a together

Comment: so the link names have always the same structure: 2 charachters, random order?

Comment: No, I mean for finding them in the matrix column, I think we have to consider both sides of the argument like a,b and b,a

Comment: so in `mat` there are link names with `b,a` that need to be assigned to `a,b`in `df`

Comment: exactly, do you have any idea that how will be possible?

Comment: should work now, please see above. it is important to load the `tidyr` library and to edit the `df` before the loop. should work now.

Comment: That was great. Thank you!